# Getting an error importing Excel file into pandas selecting the usecols parameter

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to import data into pandas from an Excel file, but I'm getting an error when typing out the following:

```
energy = pd.read_excel('Indicators.xls',
                       'Energy', 
                       skiprows=17, 
                       skip_footer=38, 
                       usecols=['C','D','E','F'])
```

But I'm getting an error stating that `'C'` is not in list. When evaluating the Excel file in Excel, it clearly has a `C` column. The pandas documentation says the following:

> **usecols** : *int or list, default None*
>
> If None then parse all columns, If int then indicates last column to
>   be parsed. If list of ints then indicates list of column numbers to be
>   parsed. If string then indicates comma separated list of Excel column
>   letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are
>   inclusive of both sides.

So I'd like to import just `C` to `F`, so I've tried both suggestions as mentioned above.

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: 'C' is not in list
```

Not sure why this won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you leave out the `usecols` argument, do you get a `C` column in the resulting data frame?

Comment: I don't get C if I leave out the usecols, but using a list of integers for the columns works.

Comment: When you leave out `usecols`, what is the name of the column in your data frame that you think should be labeled `C`?

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at version you're using. If this version is older than version 0.21.0 then try to use parse_cols instead.

```
columns = 'A:L'
df = pd.read_excel(file_to_process, sheetname=sheetname, parse_cols=columns)
```

I had the same issue with usecols. After changing to parse_cols it works properly.

Comment: just as a note you can check the version with `pd.__version__`

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
dataset=pd.read_excel('testfile.xlsx',usecols="C:F")
```

Input:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F G
1  1  1  1  1  1 1
```

Output:

```
C D E F
1 1 1 1
```